# Why does creating a temporary instance not work in this case?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been learning C++11 through Bjarne Stroustrup's "A Tour of C++".

I have the following snippet of code

```
#include <random>
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution {1,6};
    distribution(generator); //Case 1 works

    auto die = bind(uniform_int_distribution<>{1,6},default_random_engine{});  //Case 2 works

    distribution(std::default_random_engine{});     //Case 3 Compiler error 
}
```

Case 3 is my own creation while case 2 comes from the book and case 1 I adapted from elsewhere.
Why does case 3 produce the compiler error below?
As far as I understand, the only difference between case 1 and case 3 is that I'm using a temporary instance of std::default_random_engine and this temporary instance seems to work in case 2
What am I missing?

Error output:

```
random.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
random.cpp:13:46: error: no match for call to ‘(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>) (std::default_random_engine)’
     distribution(std::default_random_engine{});     //Case 3 Compiler error
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/random.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/random:49,
                 from random.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/uniform_int_dist.h:164:2: note: candidate: std::uniform_int_distribution<_IntType>::result_type std::uniform_int_distribution<_IntType>::operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator&) [with _UniformRandomNumberGenerator = std::linear_congruential_engine<long unsigned int, 16807ul, 0ul, 2147483647ul>; _IntType = int; std::uniform_int_distribution<_IntType>::result_type = int] <near match>
  operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator& __urng)
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/uniform_int_dist.h:164:2: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
random.cpp:13:23: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::linear_congruential_engine<long unsigned int, 16807ul, 0ul, 2147483647ul>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::default_random_engine {aka std::linear_congruential_engine<long unsigned int, 16807ul, 0ul, 2147483647ul>}’
     distribution(std::default_random_engine{});     //Case 3 Compiler error
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/random.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/random:49,
                 from random.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/uniform_int_dist.h:169:2: note: candidate: template<class _UniformRandomNumberGenerator> std::uniform_int_distribution<_IntType>::result_type std::uniform_int_distribution<_IntType>::operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator&, const std::uniform_int_distribution<_IntType>::param_type&) [with _UniformRandomNumberGenerator = _UniformRandomNumberGenerator; _IntType = int]
  operator()(_UniformRandomNumberGenerator& __urng,
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/uniform_int_dist.h:169:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
random.cpp:13:46: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
     distribution(std::default_random_engine{});     //Case 3 Compiler error
                                              ^
```

Comment: You can't bind a mutable reference to a temporary. Case 3 tries to do that

Comment: Check e.g. [this `uniform_int_distribution::operator()` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator%28%29). The argument to the distribution is a non-constant reference, and temporary objects can not be bound by such references.

Comment: Thanks! So in the case where at method takes a const reference, I'd be able to use the form of case 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
distribution(generator);
```

`distribution` modifies the state of `generator`, and extracts a value.  On the next call, it returns a different value, using the same `generator`

```
auto die = bind(uniform_int_distribution<>{1,6},default_random_engine{});
```

Here, we copy both a `uniform_int_distribution<>{1,6}` and a `default_random_engine{}` into the bind function object.  On `()` it passes the `default_random_engine{}` to the `uniform_int_distribution<>{1,6}` via `operator()`.  The `uniform_int_distribution<>{1,6}` modifies the state of the `default_random_engine{}` and on the next call, it returns a different value, as it uses the (now modified) generator.

```
distribution(std::default_random_engine{});
```

here you attempt to bind a `random_engine&` to a temporary object.  The `distribution` wants to modify the random engine's state, which is why it is taken by reference.

By passing in a temporary, any such change would be discarded instantly.  It is easy to do this accidentally and screw up, so C++ by default does not let you bind a temporary object to a non-const lvalue reference.

The designers of C++ std wanted this error, so they took their distribution by non-const lvalue reference.  It is trying to tell you "this is a bad plan".

You can work around it:

```
template<class T>
T& as_lvalue(T&& t){ return t; }
```

now

```
distribution(as_lvalue(std::default_random_engine{}));
```

fools the compiler into thinking that the `default_random_engine` passed in is *not* a temporary.  It still goes away at the end of the line and the modification to the state of the generator, carefully done by the distribution, is discarded.

This is usually *not* what you want when generating pseudo-random objects, which is what C++11's random engine is about.

In short, you are not permitted to bind temporaries to non-constant lvalue references.  When you do so, it is an error.  When you have a parameter that is intended to be both read from and written to, and the written value is important, it is taken by non-constant lvalue reference, in order to *prevent* you from casually passing in a temporary and having the data written to it lost.

Generators are stateful.  You want to keep one around and repeatedly apply a distribution to it.